# In Survey Designer I need a Key column

Tags: list, survey-list, survey

Is it possible to create an identity column in a SharePoint survey, much like a SQL Table?

What I need is a unique ID for each response set that the taker is aware of so we can track all the other work around their survey responses.

Something like

MyPrefix-1, MyPrefix-2 etc

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint already generates an ID for each item in a list. If you want to add a prefix to that, you could use a calculated column! It would look something like this:

```
="myprefix"+[ID]
```